# add/remove class to div based on value of jquery UI range slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, uislider

Here i have bunch of div's

```
<div id="computers">
    <div class="system" data-price="299">div1 -  299</div>
    <div class="system" data-price="599">div2 -  599</div>
    <div class="system" data-price="1099">div3 -  1099</div>
</div>
```

I am using the jQuery UI slider and trying to show / hide a 'div.system' based on slider min and max values.

I have used below script

```
  $(function() {
        $('#slider-container').slider({
            range: true,
            min: 299,
            max: 1099,
            values: [ 299, 1099 ],
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
                var mi = ui.values[ 0 ];
                var mx = ui.values[ 1 ];
                filterSystem(mi, mx);
            }
        });
      $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
      " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
  });

function filterSystem(minPrice, maxPrice) {
    $("#computers div.system").hide().filter(function() {
        var price = parseInt($(this).data("price"), 10);
        return price >= minPrice && price <= maxPrice;
    }).show();
}
```

i have done this without any bugs.

but here i want to toggleClass(add/remove class) instead of hide/show 'div.system'.

How can i do this, i have tried it but i didn't

can anyone help me? here is the [DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bZmJ8/6/)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What class are you trying to toggle?

Comment: in the given script i have not mentioned, but take any example class(filtered)

Comment: Like this (basic foo class that colors the text red): http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/bZmJ8/7/?

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/bZmJ8/8/

Comment: @MelanciaUK by default i don't want to give any class